# Filter/Limit Liferay portlet list

Tags: filter, liferay, limit, portlet

I would like to know if there is a way to filter/limit the portlets (let say a category/set of portlets) that are allowed to add in a specific page other than using permissions/roles ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can filter the portlet list by customizing **liferay-display.xml** file.

```
build.xml
/docroot/
    /css/
    /js/
    /WEB-INF/
        /src/ (not created by default)
        liferay-display.xml
        liferay-plugin-package.properties
        liferay-portlet.xml
        portlet.xml
        web.xml
    icon.png
    view.jsp
```